# How to set up charging threshold in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, battery

I'm Trying to set up a charging treshold in my laptop Toshiba Satellite. 
I have tried with TLP but the batery is still at 100% and charging.

What I want is that when the AC power supply is connected, the battery charges until some level (80% for example) and then stop charging it; so my laptop con use the AC power instead of the battery.

Some people told me to just take out the battery but I want this so if the AC power is disconected, my computer doesn't shut down abruptly and use the battery as a safety.

Comment: Did you follow this - http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html?

Comment: Yes @Raphael I looked into it but the option of threshold is only available for ThinkPads and I'm using a Toshiba Satellite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLP docs state unequivocally that charge thresholds are possible for ThinkPads only. I'm not aware of any other laptop brand where you may apply thresholds within Linux.

Did you look into BIOS/UEFI setup?

Comment: Yes I already looked into the BIOS configuration and there's nothing there related to this. @linrunner

Answer (score 0):

I also want to do this and have spent quite a while looking online for a solution. There is actually a [BIOS option](https://askubuntu.com/a/991431/1170620) that lets you set the threshold to 90%. There is also a [utility for windows](https://www.trishtech.com/2017/08/extend-battery-life-span-in-fujitsu-laptops/) made by fujitsu which I think lets you set it to 80% but that may no longer be an option. I have been unable to find anything for linux, though.