# Fujitsu Battery Issue: Battery not charging when it is above 90%

Tags: battery

My laptop battery is not charging when the battery level is above 90%.
When it is below 90, say 89, then it can charge up to 100%. But again when there is some loss in battery charge, say 97, it does not charge up to 100. I am confused whether it is a hardware problem or a software problem.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 version in this laptop.

My laptop model is:

> Fujitsu Lifebook A555

Edit 1:
The answer in the thread is very useful and I am editing this question to receive some good feedback as it will help me to ask a few more questions, I am banned to ask a question due to poor response.

Comment: Batteries have a limited life span. I would suggest getting a new one.

Comment: I had changed it but no effect.

Comment: Check your BIOS settings if there is any custom charge levels set. I like this setting though.

Comment: @Yaksha , I had already tried it but did not have a way to go in, I mean when entered into the BIOS I checked every option but did not find any charge level option.

Comment: Then probably the battery has started wearing out. Check the **capacity** in Power Statistics. If you have a good number there, you shouldn't may be really worry about. Anyways, it's not charging only at the peak 10%, a small percentage of your battery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not change your batteries. This is normal behaviour of Fujitsu Lifebooks. It is a deliberate strategy to conserve battery lifetime.

Fujitsu Lifebooks are business notebooks that normally pass most of their time sitting in docking stations that are plugged in. To prevent them from permanently being charged at 100% the manufacturer has chosen to let the charge fall below 90% before charging again up to 100%.

I have 2 Lifebooks behaving the same way (at home and in the office). You can also see this in the [Fujitsu support forum](https://forum.ts.fujitsu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45676).

You can change this behaviour in BIOS: Advanced - Miscellaneous Configurations - HW Power Management - CPU Power Saving(Battery).